# MS SQL via Python pyodbc: why keep saying there's incorrect syntax?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a query saved as .sql file using MS Sql Server Management Studio:

```
select distinct *
from bom.SalesBOMSampleExplosion b
```

and I tried to read the file via python using the pyodbc package. my other query runs successfully with pretty much same setup, except this query. 
Here's the python code I used:

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db

```
def sql_reader(qry_file, server_name, database):

    server = db.connect(str('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server_name+';DATABASE='+database+';'))
    qry = open(qry_file,'r').read()
    data = pd.read_sql(qry,server)

    return data
```

but when i use the function and call the sql file:

```
server = 'sampleserver'
db = 'sampledb'
Data = sp.sql_reader(os.path.join(qry_path, 'Data.sql'), server_name=server, database=db)
```

The following error message keeps coming up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Documents/landlordlady/python codes/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    QPVData = sp.sql_reader(os.path.join(qry_path, '8-28 qpv test.sql'), server_name=server, database=db)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\landlordlady\python codes\sql_processor.py", line 30, in sql_reader
    data = pd.read_sql(qry,server)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 399, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1436, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1413, in execute
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 340, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1401, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'ÿþ

                 s e l e c t   d i s t i n c t   * 

                 f r o m   b o m . S a l e s B O M S a m p l e E x p l o s i o n   b 

 ': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'e'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am so confused! What syntax is this error talking about?!

Comment: You appear to have some encoding issue. Maybe utf-16 somewhere utf-8 was expected, or maybe you accidentally inserted spaces into your string at some point, or maybe something else.

Comment: @user2357112 so how can i fix this?

Comment: What editor did you use to create the .sql file? Also for further clarification, could you add the python code you used?

Comment: @RageCage I've edited my post! and also I used Sql server management studio to write the sql file.

Comment: Can you try copy and pasting the actual query (`select distinct * from bom.SalesBOMSampleExplosion b`) into Windows Notepad and saving it as a separate file from there, and then reading that file? That might help us triangulate on the encoding issue.

Comment: Also may be a good idea to just paste the literal query into the qry variable as a string rather than trying to read it from the file just to be sure the query is fine. (It looks fine to me but just a sanity check)

Comment: @RageCage yup by doing that it works! so that why im confused :(

Comment: Then this is almost certainly a file encoding issue. Try FlipperPA's suggestion of pasting it into a *.txt document in Notepad. This will hopefully save it in an encoding that Python will read as intended (utf-8).

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQL Server Management Studio writes .sql files as Unicode with UTF-16LE encoding, as indicated by the Byte Order Mark (BOM) `ÿþ` (corresponding to `\xFF\xFE`) in the error message.

If a file encoding is not specified, the default encoding for `open` in Python is system-dependent. So, under Python 3.6.2 on Windows ...

```python
sql_path = r"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\from_ssms.sql"
with open(sql_path, 'r') as f:
    sql = f.read()
print(sql)
```

produces

```
ÿþs e l e c t   n a m e   f r o m   s y s . t a b l e s
```

while

```python
with open(sql_path, mode='r', encoding='UTF-16LE') as f:
```

produces

```
select name from sys.tables
```